# Multiple footnote with asterisk

Tags: footnotes

I have a list of items and I would like to put an asterisk on some of these referring to a single foot note.

### Something like this:

item1
item2
item3*
item4*
item5*

Can you please suggest the right way?

### *items with specific property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

item1 item2 item3\footnote{ Common footnote.}
 item4\footnotemark[4] item5\footnotemark[4]

\setcounter{footnote}{0}
\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}

item1 item2 item3\footnote[1]{Another common footnote.}
item4\footnotemark[1] item5\footnotemark[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks. It is exactly what i was looking for.